# Control C# checkbox using variable

Tags: c#, checkbox

I have this code:

```
// code above
 checkBox1.Checked = false;
 checkBox2.Checked = false;
 checkBox3.Checked = false;
 checkBox4.Checked = false;
 checkBox5.Checked = false;
 checkBox6.Checked = false;
 checkBox7.Checked = false;
 checkBox8.Checked = false;
 checkBox9.Checked = false;
//code below
```

I have 320 checkBoxes to set cleared/false. 
How do I control checkBox(variable)?
I would like to do the following:

```
for (int counter=1; counter<321; counter++)
{
 checkBox***Put counter Variable Here***.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: how do u create those checkboxes? by code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Foreach Control in form, how can I do something to all the TextBoxes in my Form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499049/foreach-control-in-form-how-can-i-do-something-to-all-the-textboxes-in-my-form)

Comment: Are you actually naming the controls checkbox# and making them manually in code or is your code generating them?

Comment: I set a checkbox in the design menu, then the VS gives its name. I am writing first code in my question by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all the checkboxes are incremental, then you can use the [Control.ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.110).aspx) Method.

```
for (int counter=1; counter<321; counter++)
{
   var ctrl = this.Controls.Find("checkbox" + counter, true).FirstOrDefault() as CheckBox;
   if (ctrl != null)
   {
      ctrl.Checked = false;
   }
}
```

If you just want to set every checkbox, then filter the Controls collection:

```
var checkBoxes = this.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>();
foreach (CheckBox cbx in checkBoxes)
{
    cbx.Checked = false;
}
```

Comment: At the first code sample, did you mean   "checkbox" + counter, true    ?

Comment: Yes, yes I did. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

You can loop through all of the controls on the form and check for check boxes.

```
foreach (Control ctrl in Controls)
{
    if (ctrl is CheckBox)
    {
        ((CheckBox)ctrl).Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: best Answer to use...
also the most compatible way for any project :)

Answer (score 2):

```
void SetAllCheckBoxesState(Boolean isChecked) {

    foreach(Control c in this.Controls) {

        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if( cb != null ) cb.Checked = isChecked;
    }
}
```