# Replace '\n' in multiple textbox at once

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window form application, inside this application, there have several textbox and want to replace the breakline and send out as email in one click. Since i have multiple textbox, instead of writing like this:

```
 string text = textBox1.Text;
 text = text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
 string text2 = textBox2.Text;
 text2 = text2.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
 ...

        string textBody ="<tr bgcolor = '#C39BD3'><td>Name</td><td>" + text + "</td></tr>" +"<tr bgcolor = '#C39BD3'><td>Age</td><td>" + text2 + "</td></tr>" + ...
```

is there any ways to replace the line in these textbox in one time?

I try to put in a loop:

```
        for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
        {TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)this.Controls.Find("textBox" + i, true)[0]; }
```

I stuck at here. Any suggestion?

Comment: `var boxes = Controls.OfType<TextBox>().ToList();`

Comment: I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44612323/5174469) in the duplicate will be most interesting for you

Answer (score 2):

Your Form is a Control, which has a property [Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controls?view=netcore-3.1) This property "Gets the collection of controls contained within the control".

You can use [Enumerable.OfType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netcore-3.1) to filter this so you get only the TextBoxes.

> Is there any ways to replace the line in these textbox in one time?

You'll need a foreach to replace the text:

```
var textBoxesToUpdate = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>();
foreach (TextBox textBox in textBoxesToUpdate)
{
    string proposedText = textBox.Text.Replace("\n", "<br/>");
    textBox.Text = proposedText;
}
```

I also see this in your question

```
string textBody = "<tr bgcolor = '#C39BD3'><td>Name</td><td>" + text1 + "</td></tr>"
                + "<tr bgcolor = '#C39BD3'><td>Age</td><td>"  + text2 + "</td></tr>"
                + ...
```

I don't know what you want with this. Consider to edit the question and change this.

Comment: Hi Harald, Thanks for the help and suggestion. For the 'string textBody' part, because i want to send it out as email, so that part is a html table for email. The 'text1' is the textbox that let user to key in the message.

Comment: When i send it out, it read my message at one line..so i have to use the 'replace' function to break the line. But because i have many textbox, i thinking of not to replace the textbox one by one.